# vue component in bootstrap modal in a laravel foreach loop

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs3, bootstrap-modal

I have a foreach loop in a table where pay button pops up a modal for each row. In the modal I also used a vue component containing a select dropdown.

```
@foreach ($projects as $value)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{$loop->iteration}}</th>
        <td>{{$value->startDate}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->projectInvoice}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->paid}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->due}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->amount}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" id="detail" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="Detail" data-toggle="modal"   data-target="#detailModal{{$value->projectInvoice}}">
                pay
            </a>
    

            <div class="modal fade" id="detailModal{{ $value->projectInvoice }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
                 aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Pay Due Amount</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="modal-element">

                                <hr style="border:2px solid; margin-top: 2rem; color: black;">
                                <h5 class="mb-4 text-center">General journal Entry:</h5>

                                <pay-modal :accountss="{{$accounts}}"></pay-modal>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </td>
    </tr>

@endforeach
```

And the Vue component :

```
<div  class="form-group row" v-for="(key, keyIndex) in accountInfo"  :key="key.id">
    <div class="col-md-3" >
        <label v-if="keyIndex == 0">Account</label>
        <select id="yt" class="form-control select2 bg-white" name="account[][id]" v-model="key.accountId">
            <option value="" selected>Select an Account</option>
            <option v-for="(account, inde) in accounts" :key="index" :value="account.id" >{{account.AccountName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" >
        <label v-if="keyIndex == 0">Debit Amount</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="debitAmount" v-model="key.DebitAmount" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label v-if="keyIndex == 0">Credit Amount</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CreditAmount" v-model="key.CreditAmount" />
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-3">
        <br v-if="keyIndex===0">
        <button  class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-2 ml-2 " style="margin-bottom: 0;" v-if="keyIndex == Object.keys(accountInfo).length -1" @click="addAccount" title="addAccount" id="addAccount_more_fields">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
        </button>
        <button  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-2 ml-2" v-if="keyIndex >> 0" @click="removeAccount"  title="removeAccount">
            <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

the problem is the Accounts dropdown in vue is showing the dynamic option only once for the first iteration of the modal

How can I make the dropdown work for every iteration of the foreach loop